# fabric js objects deserilization

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

Hi I'm currently working on canvas project witch allow user to interact with different shapes,texts,svg objects and so on. On of the requirement is to realize recreating of state of application, for example user add some objects to canvas and modified them in some way, and then he's able to upload specific file and continue his work. I'm using fabricjs to manipulate with objects, I have tried to serialize all canvas but it isn't option cause they appear in complete disorder. So I save the state in json format, I could recreate text nodes but I don't know what to do with svg their state look like this.

```
{
"type": "path-group",
"originX": "center",
"originY": "center",
"left": 231,
"top": 146,
"width": 100,
"height": 100,
"fill": "rgba(248,231,28,1)",
"stroke": null,
"strokeWidth": 1,
"strokeDashArray": null,
"strokeLineCap": "butt",
"strokeLineJoin": "miter",
"strokeMiterLimit": 10,
"scaleX": 1,
"scaleY": 1,
"angle": 0,
"flipX": false,
"flipY": false,
"opacity": 1,
"shadow": null,
"visible": true,
"clipTo": null,
"backgroundColor": "",
"fillRule": "nonzero",
"globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
"transformMatrix": null,
"skewX": 0,
"skewY": 0,
"paths": [{
    "type": "path",
    "originX": "left",
    "originY": "top",
    "left": 9.66,
    "top": 130.67,
    "width": 232.39,
    "height": 360.46,
    "fill": "rgba(248,231,28,1)",
    "stroke": null,
    "strokeWidth": 1,
    "strokeDashArray": null,
    "strokeLineCap": "butt",
    "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
    "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
    "scaleX": 1,
    "scaleY": 1,
    "angle": 0,
    "flipX": false,
    "flipY": false,
    "opacity": 1,
    "shadow": null,
    "visible": true,
    "clipTo": null,
    "backgroundColor": "",
    "fillRule": "nonzero",
    "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
    "transformMatrix": [0.20361290742942778, 0, 0, 0.20361290742942778, 0, 0],
    "skewX": 0,
    "skewY": 0,
    "path": [
        ["M", 213.153, 436.584],
        ["c", 4.451, -2.109, 8.9, -5.104, 12.912, -9.115],
        ["c", 12.625, -12.617, 15.977, -45.43, 15.977, -45.43],
        ["s", -32.813, 3.359, -45.421, 15.978],
        ["c", -8.789, 8.787, -13.096, 19.566, -12.227, 28.074],
        ["c", -40.67, -20.011, -50.931, -42.173, -58.254, -58.277],
        ["c", 0.414, 0.566, -0.963, -1.376, 0.924, 1.251],
        ["c", -7.937, -17.513, -12.235, -35.367, -8.972, -54.361],
        ["c", 2.245, -10.532, 5.365, -18.738, 9.043, -25.465],
        ["c", 10.046, 15.523, 27.113, 26.555, 39.523, 32.923],
        ["c", 1.671, 0.861, 3.717, 0.519, 5.031, -0.843],
        ["c", 1.304, -1.353, 1.575, -3.407, 0.652, -5.056],
        ["c", -11.305, -20.258, -10.277, -44.41, -8, -59.448],
        ["c", 4.76, -2.722, 9.425, -5.556, 13.763, -9.09],
        ["c", 33.067, -26.921, 47.149, -81.743, 22.535, -105.768],
        ["c", -24.596, -24.032, -87.602, -5.843, -111.627, 18.754],
        ["l", -0.716, 0.732],
        ["c", -10.389, 10.628, -19.639, 21.582, -27.551, 33.044],
        ["c", -13.357, 3.159, -29.708, 4.752, -45.501, -0.326],
        ["c", -1.791, -0.582, -3.757, 0.088, -4.824, 1.641],
        ["c", -1.075, 1.543, -1.011, 3.62, 0.159, 5.094],
        ["c", 7.18, 9.027, 18.142, 20.537, 31.427, 28.139],
        ["c", -10.635, 26.144, -14.695, 55.221, -9.982, 89.053],
        ["c", 16.351, 103.167, 99.273, 134.736, 152.185, 127.461],
        ["l", 0.319, -0.039],
        ["c", -1.617, 8.707, 2.762, 20.321, 12.092, 29.644],
        ["c", 12.608, 12.624, 45.429, 15.977, 45.429, 15.977],
        ["s", -3.36, -32.813, -15.977, -45.43],
        ["C", 222.053, 441.679, 217.611, 438.686, 213.153, 436.584],
        ["z"]
    ],
    "pathOffset": {
        "x": 125.85227442431159,
        "y": 310.9014004211868
    }
}, {
    "type": "path",
    "originX": "left",
    "originY": "top",
    "left": 249.07,
    "top": 0,
    "width": 232.38,
    "height": 360.46,
    "fill": "rgba(248,231,28,1)",
    "stroke": null,
    "strokeWidth": 1,
    "strokeDashArray": null,
    "strokeLineCap": "butt",
    "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
    "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
    "scaleX": 1,
    "scaleY": 1,
    "angle": 0,
    "flipX": false,
    "flipY": false,
    "opacity": 1,
    "shadow": null,
    "visible": true,
    "clipTo": null,
    "backgroundColor": "",
    "fillRule": "nonzero",
    "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
    "transformMatrix": [0.20361290742942778, 0, 0, 0.20361290742942778, 0, 0],
    "skewX": 0,
    "skewY": 0,
    "path": [
        ["M", 480.549, 290.232],
        ["c", -7.188, -9.027, -18.142, -20.545, -31.429, -28.139],
        ["c", 10.636, -26.142, 14.695, -55.221, 9.982, -89.052],
        ["C", 442.753, 69.875, 359.83, 38.305, 306.918, 45.58],
        ["l", -0.326, 0.041],
        ["c", 1.616, -8.709, -2.763, -20.322, -12.092, -29.645],
        ["C", 281.89, 3.352, 249.069, 0, 249.069, 0],
        ["s", 3.36, 32.813, 15.977, 45.429],
        ["c", 4.02, 4.021, 8.463, 7.014, 12.92, 9.115],
        ["c", -4.449, 2.109, -8.899, 5.103, -12.912, 9.114],
        ["c", -12.625, 12.625, -15.977, 45.43, -15.977, 45.43],
        ["s", 32.813, -3.358, 45.423, -15.977],
        ["c", 8.787, -8.787, 13.095, -19.566, 12.227, -28.083],
        ["c", 40.677, 20.012, 50.93, 42.182, 58.261, 58.285],
        ["c", -0.414, -0.565, 0.963, 1.376, -0.923, -1.25],
        ["c", 7.936, 17.512, 12.234, 35.368, 8.972, 54.361],
        ["c", -2.245, 10.531, -5.367, 18.738, -9.043, 25.465],
        ["c", -10.046, -15.521, -27.113, -26.548, -39.524, -32.924],
        ["c", -1.671, -0.86, -3.717, -0.519, -5.03, 0.843],
        ["c", -1.306, 1.354, -1.577, 3.408, -0.654, 5.056],
        ["c", 11.305, 20.251, 10.277, 44.41, 8, 59.448],
        ["c", -4.761, 2.723, -9.425, 5.556, -13.763, 9.09],
        ["c", -33.067, 26.923, -47.149, 81.744, -22.535, 105.77],
        ["c", 24.597, 24.031, 87.603, 5.843, 111.626, -18.755],
        ["l", 0.718, -0.732],
        ["c", 10.388, -10.627, 19.63, -21.581, 27.55, -33.044],
        ["c", 13.358, -3.159, 29.709, -4.752, 45.501, 0.326],
        ["c", 1.792, 0.582, 3.758, -0.086, 4.824, -1.64],
        ["C", 481.783, 293.783, 481.719, 291.706, 480.549, 290.232],
        ["z"]
    ],
    "pathOffset": {
        "x": 365.25982983860837,
        "y": 180.22835921734554
    }
}]}
```

It seems that almost all functions serialize canvas is there a way to render  specific objects from the state and keep it the same as user has created it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you say the object appear in complete disorder, I presume you mean that the z-index of the object is not preserved. In which case you probably have two options:

1) Add a custom property to each object, and then extend the toObject() method as described in [the tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3)

2) You could try converting canvas.getObjects() to JSON directly - the objects should be in order of z-index